# Share on Facebook shows incorrect image link

Tags: php, facebook

I am using Share on Facebook button with www.facebook.com/sharer.php?etc URI. However, I have some problems. Here's what I want to do.

1. My site is kind of like a blog in which each blog has a lot of photos
2. So when people click on Share on Facebook button, I want the users to be able to choose which photo to use as Facebook thumbnail. I'm aware this is the default method of Facebook Share which is to scan the whole page for images.

However, my problem is the thumbnails won't show. I viewed the source to find that the URI to the images is incorrect. For example :

```
**SHOULD BE :** http://www.mysite.com/web/images/photo.jpg

**ACTUAL    :** http://www.mysite.com/images/photo.jpg
```

So in short, facebook fails to read the "web" in the URI. That's why the thumbnail won't show. Any idea how to fix this?

The link to the site :

```
http://www.biiiz.com/nya/blog.php?id=1
```

It's actually just a temporary hosting. 'm sure the share on FB will work fine when I move the files into their own hosting, but I'm just curious about this.

Comment: Can you link to the actual blog so we can see what the source looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You can get facebook to clear their cache and re-download your meta data by entering your URL into their linter:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Answer (score 0):

Consider [the documentation](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share/Specifying_Meta_Tags)

```
`<link rel="image_src" href="thumbnail_image" / >`
```

Answer (score 0):

FB caches for... like... ever. You can't clear it manually, so just wait until their private crawler hits your site again.